# Is there a setting to make people group files in certain groups when uploading to a Document Library?

Tags: document-library, sorting, grouping

Is there a setting(no SharePoint designer) where I can make people put objects in a grouping when they upload it? For instance, in a document library I have the Managers listed and when they upload their documents to that library I want them to put the document in their group by just simply selecting a checkbox or something. I'm pretty sure you can do this I just can't remember how. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the manager field required, then when uploading the file, they get redirected to the Editform.aspx page where they can supply this information.

If they bulk upload or use windows explorer, they bypass this though.

Comment: I'm very new to sharepoint(second day) can you explain where I can select the manager field

Comment: Go to the document library settings, click on the field, then set the radio button to required.

Answer (score 0):

The Content Organizer will automatically route documents to a location based on the information provided in the metadata columns.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-the-content-organizer-to-route-documents-HA102772938.aspx